# not all data printed in console when in function in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to program a least squares fit after a certain button is pushed IN ttk.notebook (ttk in python3, Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). As a kind of debugging tool I am using print statements towards the console. 
When the run1 button is pressed, before the readcsv button is pressed, the console stops after printing:  above inp_data1 in run1 else
But the execution of the button is ok: the button stays pressed in for 5 seconds, followed by the message in the notebook: No data selected, which disappears after 3 seconds.
When I press the run1 button again, this is the output to the console:
[]
below inp_data1 in run1 else
above inp_data1 in run1 else
In general I have to push the buttons twice in order to get the output to the console.
See below for a part of the notebook, incl the _run1 function:

```
def _create_import_data_tab(self, nb):
    # Populate the second pane. 
    frame = ttk.Frame(nb, name="import data")
    frame.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=12, columnspan=5,sticky=(N,S,E,W))
    lbl0 = ttk.Label(frame, text='Select the csv file and push the run button')
    lbl0.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W, pady=100)
    btn2=ttk.Button(frame, text='select csv file', command=self.askopenfilename2)
    btn2.grid(column=6, row=8,sticky=W, pady=25)
    self.file_opt = options = {}
    options['defaultextension'] = '.csv'
    options['filetypes'] =[('csv files', '.csv'),('all files', '.*')]
    options['initialdir'] = '.'
    options['initialfile'] = 'creep2.csv'
    options['parent'] = nb
    options['title'] = 'Select csv file'
    readVar = tk.StringVar()
    #        self.input_fields1=['']
    btn3 = ttk.Button(frame, text='Run', underline=0,
                     command=lambda v2=readVar: self._run1(v2))
    btn3l = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=readVar, name='run1')
    btn3.grid(column=6,row=10, sticky=W, pady=25)
    btn3l.grid(column=6, row=11, sticky=W, pady=25)  
    self.input_fields1=[btn2]      
    nb.add(frame, text='Import data', underline=0)         

def get_inputs1(self):
    return [entry.get() for entry in self.input_fields1]             

def askopenfilename2(self):
    #        global path2
    #        global creepData
    path2 = filedialog.askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)
    print("path2 in askopenfilename2")
    print(path2)
    #        with open(path2) as file_obj:
    #            creepReader=csv.reader(open(file_obj, newline=""), delimiter=',')
    with open(path2):
        creepReader=csv.reader(open(path2, newline=""), delimiter=',')
    self.creepData=list(creepReader)
    self.input_fields1=["data is read"]
    print("creepData in askopenfilename2 second time")
    print(repr(self.creepData))
    #        return self.creepData, self.input_fields1
def _run1(self,v2):
    inp_data1 = self.input_fields1
    if not "data is read" or "" in inp_data1:
        v2.set('you need to load data first!')
    #            self.update()
        self.after(3000,v2.set,'')  
    elif "data is read" in inp_data1:
        print("input data in run1")
        print(repr(inp_data1))
        print("input data 2 in run1")
        print(inp_data1)
        v2.set('Goto next page')
        #            self.update()
        self.after(3000,v2.set,'') 
    else:
       print("above inp_data1 in run1 else")
       print(repr(inp_data1))
       print("below inp_data1 in run1 else")
       time.sleep(5)
       v2.set('No data selected')
       #           self.update()
       self.after(3000,v2.set,'')
```

Comment: Consider writing an mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.